# Is there a well-known notion of orientability for finite geometries?

Tags: finite-geometry, orientation

I'm wondering if the notion of an orientable/non-orientable manifold has any reasonable extension that allows for a similar classification of finite geometries.

For example, the real projective plane is non-orientable.  Does this somehow mean that a finite projective plane is "non-orientable" too?

I would also be interested in a definition that applies over a narrower domain, e.g. a notion of orientability for finite *ordered* geometries or something like that.

Comment: There is a classical notion of [oriented matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_matroid), also known as chirotope, so I guess you could define an "oriented projective plane" as a projective plane structure together with an oriented matroid whose underlying matroid is that of alignment in the projective plane.

Comment: I don't understand the second paragraph. In particular, the complex projective plane is orientable. Is there some reason to regard the real field as closer to finite fields than the complex field?

Comment: Oriented matroids are used in MacPherson's theory of combinatorial differential manifolds, but I don't think that this is the kind of thing GMB is asking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do that you would need a notion of a non-orientable and an orientable linear transformation, i.e., essentially a notion of a "positive" and "negative" determinant, where "positive" determinants would form a subgroup *not* containing the element $-1$.  This works for the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if the prime $p$ satisfies $p\equiv 3 (mod\; 4)$.

Thus denoting by $G\subset (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\ast$ the index-2 subgroup consisting of the quadratic residues modulo $p$, one obtains an "orientable double cover" $M=(F^3\setminus\{0\})/G$, where $F=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Quotienting $M$ by the ("orientation-reversing") antipodal map, you get the projective plane over $F$.

Comment: Why does '$-1$' have to be 'negative' (other than psychology)?  Couldn't one view negative as 'not the square class of $1$' (as it seems that you do), and divide up that way?  I guess that, as someone who doesn't study orientability, I mean to ask whether the *additive*, or only the *multiplicative*, structure of the determinants matters.  If the latter, then there's nothing particularly special about $-1$.